# How do I mask the contents of a WPF Wrappanel?

Tags: wpf, silverlight, xaml, wrappanel

Hi and thanks for looking!

## Background

This is an extension on this question:

[How do I slide child items up or down inside a WPF wrappanel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8691394/how-do-i-slide-child-items-up-or-down-inside-a-wpf-wrappanel)

In which I asked how I could programattically scroll the contents of a `WrapPanel` up or down on a button click.  This question was kindly answered and the accepted solution works well.

## Problem

Now that my thumbnails in the `WrapPanel` scroll up and down on a button click, how do I mask the `WrapPanel` so that the tiles don't show when they are outside of frame?  For example, I have a `StackPanel` above the `WrapPanel` that holds the scroll up and down buttons, but when I scroll down, the thumbnails cover up the `StackPanel` above them (and the buttons).  Here is my XAML so far, please note that the thumbnails are added to the `WrapPanel` at runtime:

## Update

Using Dave Clemmer's XAML, my layout is steadier, but then I still end up with the contents of the `WrapPanel` eclipsing the `StackPanel` above it.  Please see these screen grabs taken before and after the scroll event:

BEFORE SCROLL-

[image: Before Scroll]

AFTER SCROLL-
[image]

## Update 2

*Set canvas to red background per Dave's comment below.*

BEFORE SCROLL-

[image]

AFTER SCROLL-

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the edits, Dave.  That just taught me a few things.  Future questions will look better!  Cheers.

Comment: If you need help with scrolling you need to post you XAML with the ScrollViewer.

Comment: My pleasure.  So, you want to scroll the WrapPanel and not the StackPanel above it?  If so, it would be easier to do something more along the lines of approach 1 in your previous question, and put everything in a Grid, with the StackPanel in row 0 and the WrapPanel with a ScrollViewer in row 1.

Comment: Thanks again Dave.  Your assumption is correct. If I do that, however, will I end up with a scroll bar or can I still hope for a nice scroll motion in response to a button click event?  I didn't want to confuse the issue, but I am actually playing with the Kinect SDK--when hand waves up, thumbnails go up.  Hand waves down, thumbnails go down.  So I definitely want to stay away from scroll bars.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I wouldn't call this intuitive, but in the end, this worked:

```
 <Border Grid.Row="1" Background="Transparent" ClipToBounds="True">       
            <Canvas>
                <WrapPanel x:Name="spContainer"  
                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth,  
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}">
                </WrapPanel>
            </Canvas>
 </Border>
```

Adding the border did the trick.  Thanks to Dave for all of your help!

Comment: Thanks again Dave.  I couldn't have gotten there without your help.

Comment: wouldn't it have been sufficient to specify cliptobounds on the canvas?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you do not want scrollbars (no `ScrollViewer`) and want the `StackPanel` to be fixed.  Keep the `StackPanel` and `WrapPanel` in separate `Grid` rows such as:

```
<Grid> 
    <Grid.RowDefinitions> 
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" /> 
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/> 
    </Grid.RowDefinitions> 
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="30,10,10,10" Name="stackPanel1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" Orientation="Horizontal" >  
        <Label Content="Home Navigator v0.1" FontFamily="Tahoma" FontSize="30" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="White" />  
        <Button Content="Close" Height="50" Click="Button_Click" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>  
        <Button Content="Scroll Down" Height="50" Click="ScrollDown" VerticalAlignment="Top"></Button>  
    </StackPanel>  
    <Canvas Grid.Row="1">  
        <WrapPanel x:Name="spContainer"  
                   Width="{Binding ActualWidth,  
                           RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Canvas}}}">  
        </WrapPanel>      
    </Canvas>  
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks Dave, your suggested XAML helps to make a better layout, but I am still having the original problem.  Please see my updates above.

Comment: Hmm, strange.  Either you are rendering the images outside of the Canvas in your AnimateScroll method or elsewhere, or (I doubt), the Canvas got expanded outside of its grid row.  Can you determine which of these problems it is (such as putting a red background on your Canvas)?

Comment: Please see new screen grabs above, Dave.  Thanks again!